# Too many parameters error?

Tags: java, web-services, maven, axis

I am generating classes from WSDL using `axistools-maven-plugin`. But the generated class has too many params as constructor argument and is giving below error.

> Too many parameters, parameter "myParam" is exceeding the limit of 255 words eligible for method parameters.

Comment: Can you share your WSDL file?

Comment: It is third party WSDL and can't b shared.

Comment: Using Axis 1.4 or Axis 2?

Comment: Using Axis 1.4 version

Comment: You can try using -W switch while generating code. It will turn off support for "wrapped" document/literal. https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/reference.html

Comment: where to include it in plugin?

Comment: Sample http://mojo.codehaus.org/axistools-maven-plugin/examples/simple.html       Param http://mojo.codehaus.org/axistools-maven-plugin/wsdl2java-mojo.html#noWrapped

Comment: It has no property called nowrap.

Comment: Check the sample on above url and add following <noWrapped>true</noWrapped>